# Ag grid customize group row cells with aggFunc

Tags: angular, grouping, ag-grid

I am trying to set a group with ag grid enterprise:

Here is an exmaple of my data row : 
{'service': 'service A', 'agent': 'agent AAA', '5-5-2018': true, '6-5-2018': false}

I would like to group on the field 'service', I also have a custom component for cell rendering on fields with date.
Here is my colDefs :

```
[
 {field: 'agent', 'headerName': "Agents", hide: true},
 {field: 'service', 'headerName': "Services", cellRenderer: 
    'agGroupCellRenderer', rowGroup: true, hide: true},
 {field: '5-5-2018', 'headerName': "05 - 05 - 2018", cellRenderer: 
  "customCell",  aggFunc: "presence"},
 {field: '6-5-2018', 'headerName': "06 - 05 - 2018", cellRenderer: 
  "customCell",  aggFunc: "presence"}
];
```

"presence" aggFunc only show a string '5/5' for now.

So the custom Cell works fine, I do have my groups and the agg data for each column, but custom Cell is applied to the group cells too, which in my case is not good.

How can I manage to redefine the cell renderer for group cells ( cells for the group row ) ?

Here is a screen shot : 
[image: here]